# merge time periods using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to convert time periods by merging and counting  them using XSLT and I don't know how to do it.
Example:
I have the following periods:

```
<root>
        <period begin="2014-06-01" end="2014-06-15" />
        <period begin="2014-06-07" end="2014-06-10" />
        <period begin="2014-06-08" end="2014-06-12" />
</root>
```

These should be converted in the following periods:

```
<root>
        <mergedperiod begin="2014-06-01" end="2014-06-07" amount="1"/>
        <mergedperiod begin="2014-06-07" end="2014-06-08" amount="2"/>
        <mergedperiod begin="2014-06-08" end="2014-06-10" amount="3"/>
        <mergedperiod begin="2014-06-10" end="2014-06-12" amount="2"/>
        <mergedperiod begin="2014-06-12" end="2014-06-15" amount="1"/>
</root>
```

any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I think you mean *split*, not *merge*. Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: It's a bit of both. First I'm splitting them and then merging them. I'm using XSLT 2.0

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you need to create a sorted list of **all** distinct dates (begin OR end). Then create a period for each consecutive pair in the list. Finally, match up each (new) period with the original periods that overlap it, and count the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- generate a sequence of all distinct dates, in chronological order -->
    <xsl:variable name="dates" as="xs:date*">
      <xsl:perform-sort>
        <xsl:sort />
        <xsl:sequence select="distinct-values(
              (period/xs:date(@begin), period/xs:date(@end)))" />
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- store the set of input <period> elements for future use -->
    <xsl:variable name="allPeriods" select="period" />

    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to (count($dates) - 1)">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="." />
        <!-- how many periods include the current bracket between this date
             and the next one? -->
        <xsl:variable name="numPeriods" select="count($allPeriods[
           xs:date(@begin) le $dates[$i] and xs:date(@end) ge $dates[$i+1]])" />
        <!-- if there is at least one, output a new <mergedperiod> -->
        <xsl:if test="$numPeriods gt 0">
          <mergedperiod begin="{$dates[$i]}" end="{$dates[$i+1]}"
                        amount="{$numPeriods}" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet avoids outputting a `mergedperiod` where the `amount` would be zero (i.e. if your input has non-contiguous periods).  If you do in fact want the zeros included then just remove the `if`

Edit: from the comments, if you want to merge contiguous periods that share the same count then the easiest way to do that would be to generate the initial list of merged periods into a variable and then post process that to do the merge:

```
    <xsl:variable name="pass1">
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to (count($dates) - 1)">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="." />
        <!-- how many periods include the current bracket between this date
             and the next one? -->
        <xsl:variable name="numPeriods" select="count($allPeriods[
           xs:date(@begin) le $dates[$i] and xs:date(@end) ge $dates[$i+1]])" />
        <!-- if there is at least one, output a new <mergedperiod> -->
        <xsl:if test="$numPeriods gt 0">
          <mergedperiod begin="{$dates[$i]}" end="{$dates[$i+1]}"
                        amount="{$numPeriods}" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <root>
      <!-- adjacent periods with the same amount -->
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$pass1/*" group-adjacent="@amount">
        <!-- where the end of one lines up with the start if the next -->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current- group()" group-starting-with="*[not(@begin = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@end)]">
          <mergedperiod begin="{@begin}"
              end="{current-group()[last()]/@end}"
              amount="{@amount}"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
```

Comment: nice that it filters out the periods with an amount of 0

Comment: On second thought, perhaps there needs to be step 4 to merge consecutive (new) periods that happen to have the same count?

Comment: that would indeed be an improvement.

Comment: @coen I've added a possible (as yet untested) approach to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** added grouping so duplicates are avoided.

Here's a possible answer, this basically generates a mergedperiod for either the beginn or end attribute if there is a next bigger date:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:variable name="periods">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="period/@begin|period/@end"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$periods/*" group-by="@begin">
            <xsl:sort select="@begin"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="period/@begin|period/@end">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextdate"
        select="min(for $i in //period/(@end|@begin)[xs:date(.) gt $date] return xs:date($i))"/>
    <xsl:if test="string($nextdate) != ''">
        <mergedperiod begin="{$date}" end="{$nextdate}"
            amount="{count(//period[xs:date(@begin) le $date and xs:date(@end) ge $nextdate])}"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorting is the lesser problem with your approach; duplicates are the greater: add a period beginning on 2014-06-12 to the input to see why.